# how to draw text in QQuickItem

Tags: qt, qquickitem

I've been searching the internet how to draw or render text on QQuickItem but to no avail. I opt not to use QQuickPaintedItem which uses QPainter paint() function. Aside from that there is also a known issue of QQuickPaintedItem on iOS retina display devices where the display is blurred and edges were not sharp.

Please advise any possible work-around on this.

Answer (score 2):

> Since QtDeclarative has been deprecated already, I opt not to use
>   QQuickPaintedItem which uses QPainter paint() function

That statement doesn't make a lot of sense. `QtDeclarative` is QtQuick1, `QQuickPaintedItem` is part of the QtQuick2 module and has nothing to do with `QtDeclarative`. Furthermore, even though it uses `QPainter` it is still hardware accelerated using OpenGL.

Overloading a custom `QQuickItem` to draw text in it manually, without assistance from `QPainter` or any other similar class will be a very complex task.

A `QQuickItem` is basically the class behind QML's `Item` element. QML also has a `Text` element. QML has been designed for rapid UI development, it is entirely pointless to draw the text manually. You don't need any C++ for this, only QML:

```
Item {
    Text {
        text: "something"
    }
}
```

Take a look at the `Text` element and its properties, you can specify font, color and whatnot. You can directly use the element as a source for graphics effects too.

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion on the above statement. I know already about Text QML Type. However, I wanted to render text into each custom geometry nodes which formed a single QSGNode. Is it possible to render a text after creating the geometry node? The same with QPainter behavior where you can draw a rectangle then draw text on it after. TIA.

Comment: You cannot render text into a geometry node. Whatever is it that you are trying to achieve, I think you are going the wrong way about it. You can build geometry for text manually, and use it in a geometry node, but I'd say that's a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @ddriver. Can you give advise and tips what should I do to draw this [sample](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2a61oxx.jpg) with text inside each polygon.

Comment: @user1870074 - you could `QQuickItem` to implement the actual "arrowy thingie", it should be easy enough to do and just put a Text element inside of it. This way it will be more useful and easier to work with. QML is modular, one item renders one thing, there is no QML element which renders more than one feature at a time. Unless you use `QQuickPaintedItem` in which case you can use `QPainter` to draw multiple features.

Comment: What if you tried first using Text (in QML) and JS and saw that it is just too slow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use QPainter to draw on a QImage like a canvas.  Then you can turn this into a QSGTexture that can be assigned to a QSGSimpleTextureNode.

Here is an excerpt of code I recently wrote to do this:

```
QColor color("steelblue");
QRect rect(0,0,aw, ah);
for(auto ch: m_charList){
    QImage canvas(rect.width(), rect.height(), QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
    canvas.fill(QColor("transparent"));
    QPainter painter(&canvas);

    QFont font = painter.font();
    //font.setPixelSize(48);
    font.setPixelSize(rect.width());
    font.setBold(true);
    painter.setFont(font);
    painter.setPen(color);

    QRect bounding = QRect(0, 0, rect.width(), rect.height());
    painter.drawText(0, 0, rect.width(), rect.height(), Qt::AlignCenter, ch, &bounding);

    QSGTexture *texture = this->window()->createTextureFromImage(canvas);
    m_textureList[ch] = texture;
}
```

The repo with the full working code in context is [here](https://github.com/Demolishun/MeetupGameHackathon1).

There are MANY reasons to want to render like this.  You can do rotations in 3D space to QSGNodes for one.